# how to use IB_DESIGNABLE in ViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want to use *IB_DESIGNABLE* in UIViewController ,just like

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property(strong,nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@end
...
```

then I can see the view in the viewcontroller of storyboard,but I failed,the tableview didn't show in the storyboard,but I can see it when I run it in the iOS Simulator.
My question is :how can I use IB_DESIGNABLE in the viewcontroller  code?

I know I can make a subclass of UIView (e.g..TestView),use put the tableview and tableviewdatasource and delegate in TestView and use IB_DESIGNABLE in TestView, then in the storyboard ,change the view of view controller's view to TestView,then I can the tableView has rendered in the storyboard ,but it is to waste time...

Answer (score 0):

> how can I use IB_DESIGNABLE in the viewcontroller code?

You can't. It is not view controllers, but *views*, that are IB_DESIGNABLE.